# Which method should be used to achieve the most accurate world tracking experience on ARKit?

Tags: swift, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arkit, aranchor

My company is developing an Augmented Reality app for a client, using ARKit, and they want the best world tracking experience on iOS. We have told them that this is not an exact science and that small variations are perfectly normal, but they want us to do anything possible to minimize errors, drifts and movements from holograms.

We have tested some `ARHitTestResult` examples on Unity and some others that use `ARImageAnchor`, but we can't decide on which is the best. It seems that using an `ARImageAnchor` improves tracking, but I am not sure if that is really the case or if this is just an optical illusion.

What's the best – `ARImageAnchor` vs plain `ARAnchor`?

Please advise or share any Unity/Apple documentation on this matter.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Recommendations for accurate tracking

Any anchor in ARKit (`ARFaceAnchor`, `ARGeoAnchor`, `ARImageAnchor`, `ARPlaneAnchor`, etc), inherits from `ARAnchor` parent class and, in some cases, conforms to `ARTrackable` protocol.

Every anchor in ARKit has its purpose (for instance, `ARPlaneAnchor` is a special version of ARAnchor that designated for plane detection process). I don't think that one anchor is more precise than another. All you need to provide for a robust tracking results is a good lighting condition, distinguishable 3D surfaces and high-contrast textures on real-world objects. Also pre-saved `ARWorldMap` is an excellent starting point for a persistent AR experience.

Don't use `repetitive texture/objects patterns` and `surfaces with solid colors` when tracking your scene. For best tracking results don't track moving objects. You need only static environment. And I should say that all Apple devices are good-calibrated for tenable and precise AR experience.

#### Additional tips for robust AR experience

If you turn on image detection option in 6 DOF `ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()` you'll get `ARImageAnchor` objects (for each detected image) that are a data on the position and orientation of images detected in a world-tracking AR session. That doesn't improve a precision of world tracking but that slows down a processing speed.

```
guard let refImgs = ARReferenceImage.referenceImages(inGroupNamed: "ARGroup", 
                                                           bundle: nil) 
else { fatalError("Missing expected resources.") }

let config = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
config.detectionImages = refImgs
config.maximumNumberOfTrackedImages = 3
session.run(config, options: [.resetTracking, .removeExistingAnchors])
```

A `world-tracking session` with image tracking enabled can simultaneously track only a small number of images. You can track more images with [ARImageTrackingConfiguration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arimagetrackingconfiguration). But image detection accuracy and performance are considerably reduced with larger numbers of detection images.

With `ARImageTrackingConfiguration`, ARKit establishes a 3D space not by tracking the motion of the device relative to the world, but solely by detecting and tracking the motion of known 2D images in view of the camera. `Image-only tracking` lets you anchor virtual content to known images only when those images are in view of the camera. `World tracking with image detection` lets you use known images to add virtual content to the 3D world, and continues to track the position of that content in world space even after the image is no longer in view. `World tracking` works best in a stable, nonmoving environment. You can use image-only tracking to add virtual content to known images in more situations — for example, an advertisement inside a moving subway car.

So, using `ARImageAnchors` in your scene doesn't add the extra layer of quality for World Tracking Results. Check [Recognizing Images in an AR Experience](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/recognizing_images_in_an_ar_experience) article for detailed info.

Comment: Thanks for many articles you shared on SO. Will `ARGeoAnchor` or `ARGeoTrackingConfiguration` provide better accuracy than the plain old `ARWorldTrackingConfiguration` in applicable cities?

Comment: It makes no sense to compare ARWorldTrackingConfig and ARGeoTrackingConfig since they are created for different purposes. ARWorldTrackingConfig provides a high accuracy at short distances (mostly indoors), and ARGeoTrackingConfig gives you the ability to attach geo anchors (outdoors) within the Apple Maps coverage area, but with an accuracy of [plus/minus 16 feet](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253979690?sortBy=best) (±4.9 m). And remember that the accuracy of altitude value of ARGeoAnchor is noticeably imprecise.

Comment: Thanks. world tracking and geo-tracking are 2 of the 4 spatial tracking configurations. In terms of outdoor usage, they are more practical than the other 2 (orientation is 3DOF, positional is for low-res VR). I agree that world tracking works better in short distance and indoors, but it is the only alternative for outdoor world scale tracking in places without geo-tracking map imagery. My question is - is geo-tracking equal to "world tracking plus geo anchors" in world scale?

Comment: World tracking uses VIO (camera imagery with IMU data) + LiDAR data. Geo tracking uses VIO + GPS data + server data from Apple Maps. World tracking is more advanced in such capabilities as `ARWorldMaps` support, `scene reconstruction` support, `multi-user` experience support, `driven face tracking` support (second simultaneous config), etc.

Comment: But if speaking roughly, YES, these two configs are almost the same. ))

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what @andy-jazz posted:
Use `ARAnchor`
You should only use an `ARImageAnchor` when you actually want to trigger an experience from an image.
Otherwise using them might even be detrimental as the initially recognized position and rotation can be slightly off especially with extreme viewing angles.
This will get adjusted when you you are facing your image more directly, causing your content to drift if it is parented to this image.

Using an image anchor also leads to the usability limitation of users having to have the image present to use your app.

**Tip:**
If you have any influence on what iOS device the client will use with this app make sure it has LIDAR. In my experience this leads to faster and more consistent tracking especially in low light conditions.